# Is there a way to relate the axis ratios of 2D slices of lots of different ellipsoids to the probable distribution of axis ratios in 3D?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I'm working with an image which shows me a 2D slice of large number of shapes ~3000 which in 3D can all be represented by an ellipsoid with axies a,b and c. I want to find the distribution of axis ratios b/a and c/a for the 3D shape. For this problem I will have to assume b=c.

As the image is 2D it only contains slices of the ellipsoids and it is impossible to know for sure what the true axis ratios are. Taking the 2D ratios is an underestimate, I was wondering if anyone had any idea of a statistical method/package to correct the 2D ratios to bring them closer to those of the 3D ratios.

[image: ellipsoid with oblique cross section]

Currently I am just using the 2D ratios

Comment: 1. Are you trying to estimate the parameters of one ellipsoid using 3000 slices? Or the parameters of 3000 different ellipsoids, and you have one slice of each? 2. Do you have any information about how the slices are taken w.r.t. the original ellipsoid(s)? e.g. are the slices all parallel to the 'a' axis (as it appears in your image)? 3. What format are your data in? Do you already have the parameters of the 2D slices (e.g. $f_0, f_1, f_2$)? What about the angle the slice is taken at?

Comment: NB1 if you just have one slice of an ellipsoid in 3D space with no extra information, I don't think it's possible to reconstruct the original axes ratios. NB2 If you want a formula to do the calculation, you may be better off posting at [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com). And then ask questions about implementing this in MATLAB here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.